# Python program is outputting a strange value to my 16x2 Character LCD

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I've built a small program with a Tkinter GUI to let me enter 2 lines of text and make it display it on the character screen. It all works pretty neatly until I press apply text, because then I just seem to get a weird value on both lines of the LCD.
e.g.
Wanted line 1: "`Test`"
Wanted line 2: "`Please work`"

Actual result

Line 1: `.3047332040L.304`
Line 2: `7332320L`

This is my code:

```
__author__ = 'David'
from Tkinter import *
from Adafruit_CharLCD import Adafruit_CharLCD
from time import sleep
import psutil
chargui = Tk()
lcd = Adafruit_CharLCD()
lcd.begin(16, 1)


class FrameWork:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()


        # Creation
        self.lbl_enter1 = Label(frame, text="Enter the first line:")
        self.lbl_enter2 = Label(frame, text="Enter the second line:")

        self.ent_line1 = Entry(frame)
        self.ent_line2 = Entry(frame)

        self.btn_apply = Button(frame, text="Apply Text", command=self.applymessage)
        self.btn_cpum = Button(frame, text="CPUMem", command=self.CPUMem)
        self.btn_quit = Button(frame, text="Quit", command=frame.master.destroy)


        # Griding
        self.lbl_enter1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E, padx=2)
        self.lbl_enter2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E, padx=2)

        self.ent_line1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.ent_line2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

        self.btn_apply.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, padx=24)
        self.btn_cpum.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W, padx=85)
        self.btn_quit.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E)

    def applymessage(self):
        lcd.clear()
        lcd.message(str(self.ent_line1))
        lcd.message(str(self.ent_line2))


    def CPUMem(self):
        while 1:
            lcd.clear()
            lcd.message("CPU: " + str(psutil.cpu_percent()) + "%\n")
            lcd.message("MEM: " + str(psutil.virtual_memory().percent) + "%")
            sleep(1)


g = FrameWork(chargui)
chargui.mainloop()
```

Don't mind the `CPUMem` function. This function works nicely.
It's just `applymessage(self):` that gives me trouble. I get no error at all. If I remove `srt()` from the 2 lcd.message functions though, it says it can't concatenate a string with an int.
Any solutions?

Edit:
I tried to just print the value to the console instead of putting it onto the LCD, and it still gives me the weird values (are they memory locations? wild guess) for both lines
Line 1: `.3047815368L.3047815608L`
Line 2: `.3047815368L.3047815648L`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found, the LCD has nothing to do with it. The problem is trying to convert a Tkinter `Entry` object into a `str`:

```
str(self.ent_line1)
```

calls a [special method](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#representations), `self.ent_line1.__str__()` to get the string representation of the object (as does `print`). There is no expectation that `__str__` is defined to do something useful.

Actually, investigating using the interactive shell, you can find that this special method is defined in a parent class, and it's docstring is "Return the window path name of this widget." That's what you're seeing.

What you actually want, the text typed into the widget as a string, is given by [`get()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.get-method):

```
print self.ent_line1.get()
```

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT: Hm, it appears that you don't need to couple widgets to variables at all, as per the other answer to this question. The few times I've used TK that's the way I've always done it, but calling `get()` directly on the widget is probably certainly easier in this instance. I'm leaving this answer up for additional background.*

I'm far from an expert in tkinter but unless someone more knowledgeable replies, I'll do my best.

The problem is that you're attempting to print the widget objects themselves, but the API doesn't work quite like that. If you read through the [documentation for the `Entry` widget](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry.html), you'll see that you need to associate a `StringVar` instance with it. [This page](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/control-variables.html) has some more details, and there's a [section in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html?highlight=tkinter#coupling-widget-variables) too.

So, you'll need to do something like this when building your `Entry` wigets:

```
self.ent_line1_text = StringVar()
self.ent_line2_text = StringVar()
self.ent_line1 = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.ent_line1_text)
self.ent_line2 = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.ent_line2_text)
```

And then your `applymessage()` would look something like:

```
def applymessage(self):
    lcd.clear()
    lcd.message(self.ent_line1.get())
    lcd.message(self.ent_line2.get())
```

As well as the `get()` method to retrieve the current contents of the entry box, there's also `set()` if you need to change it programmatically (e.g. to initialise the text boxes with some default text).

Comment: Correct, `StringVar`s are optional, and in most cases completely unnecessary.